# How to add rows to datagridview while datagridview is bind

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I filled with data.

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

 con = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE "'", con);
 ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
 con .Fill(ds, "TABLE");
```

My problem is I have to add rows manually like the code below but it is just add one row.But what I need foreach's count row.

```
foreach (var a in names.Split(new char[] { ';' }))
{
    DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
    dataGridView2.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Value = a.ToString();
    i = i +1;
}
```

Comment: Set the value in the DataTable.  You won't need that "i" variable.  I don't see how "table" is connected to your query.  Doesn't compile either.  "con" is usually used for the data connection, but you have it as your Adapter — that's a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
DataRow drToAdd = dataTable.NewRow();
drToAdd[3] = a.ToString();
dataTable.Rows.Add(drToAdd);
```